# Line break between table and plot with pdf_document output in R Markdown

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, r-markdown, line-breaks

I'm creating a document with PDF output in R Markdown.

My code creates a number of tables and figures in a "for" loop, **within the same code chunk**. All the tricks I've seen to create a line break in a PDF document - with all sorts of combinations and permutations of preceding slashes and spaces (e.g., newline, linebreak, 
, &nbsp, etc) are not working. So, I decided to cut some corners and just increase the plot space in my ggplot2 margins to create the illusion of more white space between my table and my graph.

- Ideally, I'd love to know how to actually **insert white space ( a line, or several lines) properly within a single code chunk**, without getting an error.
- However, I'd also settle for figuring out why the following code "works" to produce extra space in my ggplot2 plot when I have some background color (first plot) but ***doesn't*** work when the background color is white!!? This is truly bizarre behavior folks!

See my screenshot below and the code, with two identical code chunks - except the background color of the plot - where one plot with a light beige background shows the desired "white space" between the table and the plot title, and the plot following (white background) does not show the same "white space".

[image: R markdown pdf output - first plot has yellow background with linebreak, second plot is white background without linebreak]

````
---
title: "I need a line break"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, 
                  include = TRUE, 
                  message = FALSE, 
                  warning = FALSE, 
                  error = FALSE)
```

```{r, results = "asis", fig.height = 2}
for (i in 1) {
mytable <- kable((iris[c(1,2),]), booktabs = TRUE)

print(mytable)

myplot <- ggplot(iris) + 
labs(title = "Gorgeous plot") +
geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
theme_void() +
theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#FFFEEB", color = "white"),
  plot.margin = unit(c(1, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))
print(myplot)
}
```


```{r, results = "asis", fig.height = 2}
for (i in 1) {
mytable <- kable((iris[c(1,2),]), booktabs = TRUE)

print(mytable)

myplot <- ggplot(iris) + 
labs(title = "Gorgeous plot") +
geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white"),
  plot.margin = unit(c(1, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))

print(myplot)
}
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you add linebreaks with cat to solve your problem? E.g.

````
---
title: "I need a line break"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, 
                  include = TRUE, 
                  message = FALSE, 
                  warning = FALSE, 
                  error = FALSE)
```

```{r, results = "asis", fig.height = 2}
for (i in 1:2) {
mytable <- kable((iris[c(1,i),]), booktabs = TRUE)
print(mytable)
cat("\\ ")
cat("\\linebreak")
cat("\\linebreak")
cat("\\linebreak")
myplot <- ggplot(iris) + 
labs(title = "Gorgeous plot") +
geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  theme_void()
print(myplot)
cat("\\linebreak")
cat("\\linebreak")
}
```
````

[image: example_1.png]

(The `cat("\\ ")` is needed so that there is a line to end)

Comment: Thanks! That did work. I had to add an extra `cat("\\ ")` after the `cat("\\linebreak")` as well, but yes - that did the trick. I have to admit, I'm still curious about the weird spacing issue in the plot, but I can always ask another question or post an issue on github about it. I'll flip you the bounty asap!

Comment: Thanks @Nova, I'm not sure about your weird spacing issue though - I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on my system (macOS, R v4.0.3, RStudio v1.3.1093) so you would need to provide more details e.g. the output from `sessionInfo()` and versions of pandoc / cairo / whatever you're using to render the .Rmd. I suspect it has to do with voiding the theme (i.e. `theme_void()` cf. `theme_classic()`) but without being able to reproduce the issue I couldn't come up with a solution sorry